# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Connection to Azure database uses router ip address

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-connection, ssms

I am accessing an Azure Database via MS SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.  I do not own the Azure database that I am connecting to.

I have connected to this database in the past (with occasional difficulties) but for some reason when I now use the `Connect to Server` I get the following error:

[image: SSMS Error]

The odd thing is that IP referred to in the error message is my router's IP address as opposed to the IP addressed assigned to me (I checked my IP address using ipchicken([IPCHICKEN](http://ipchicken.com)).

Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Just confirming that you are using Azure SQL Database as a service. In that case, you need to create a new SQL server firewall rule and add the ip that the error shows you there.
In the portal, Go to your SQL Server -> Settings -> Firewall -> Add client IP.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/

Azure is taking the ip address of your router and not your local ip. You can try using http://ifconfig.me/ip to get what is your external facing IP.

Comment: I am not the Azure DBA so I cannot answer you question nor can I add client IPs.  However it turns out that the IP Address from https://www.ipchicken.com/ is different than http://ifconfig.me/ip